# How would I obtain the versions/dialects of SQL used for these online SQL editors?

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL by running test queries using online SQL editors below.

1. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc
2. https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql
3. http://sqlfiddle.com/

I've noticed that each editor has some different keywords/syntax that it supports/ doesn't support. For example, 1 supports "WITH temp_table AS (some_query) SELECT ... " which I couldn't get to work on the other two. Also, 3 supports copying a table using "CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT * FROM old_table" which I couldn't get to work on the other 2.

Can someone shed some light on the different dialects of SQL and which are used for these online editors?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk lets you chose dbms.

Comment: Apart from this question being a request to compile a list of things which is off-topic, any answers are going to be inherently obsolete as these websites will continue to change the DB versions they are offering.

Comment: Perhaps I should change my question to how to obtain the version of SQL used on these websites if you think that is more fitting. As I believe most beginners will google "sql editor" to test as they learn and come across similar syntactical differences, I think the question of which versions are being used is a very natural one.

Comment: Rather than pin down a specific version of RDBMS for a public site that lets you play with things it's more useful to know that 1) there *is* an ANSI/ISO SQL standard (updated every few years) and 2) virtually no RDBMS in existence completely adheres to this standard, with each having their own idiosyncrasies in syntax, sometimes even for very basic things like the types used for character data, dates and times. For "stable" experimentation a local setup or a site that lets you select the engine is vastly preferable to the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to know. Do you have any recommendations for local setups to use?

Comment: haha @JeroenMostert "no rdms in existence is compliant".  Gserg: yes, the engine specific data is inherently obsolete, but the method is useful(ish), at least up until the method changes (and that means it's probably stableish).  Knowing that there are various different ways to do it is also useful to know, as is the fact that the standards aren't completely implemented and that you'll have to check on engine specific methods (and not just for this).

Comment: Specific software recommendations are off-topic for SO, so I can't tell you that for Windows, SQL Server Express would be the natural choice while on Linux or MacOS, MySQL or PostgreSQL with any front-end of your choice would be logical, because that would go against the nature of the site -- so I won't. (Which also illustrates why this sort of thing is discouraged -- I've probably offended some Oracle users now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WITH is not supported in SQLite until v3.8.3, and not on MySQL until v8, which is why that only works on 1, and SQLite lacks the SELECT INTO ability, which is why that only works on 3.  Some of those SQL engines on sqlfiddle should support the WITH construction, though.  I tested with this:

```
WITH temp_table AS (select * from test) 
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

and every engine allowed it EXCEPT mySQL, which is expected because it didn't support WITH in 5.6.

Thanks to Jeroen Mostert for pointing out that not every browser supports WebSQL, so the version shown for those (the SQLite engines) will depend.

Number 1 (w3schools) as of 11/24/2021, SQLite 3.36.0.
Number 2 (mycompiler), SQLite 3.7.17.
Number 3 (sqlfiddle), lets you choose the engine, and they are:

```
MySQL 5.6.48; 
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production;
PostgreSQL 9.6.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.6.17-2.pgdg90+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit;
PostgreSQL 9.3.25 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.3.25-1.pgdg90+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit;
SQLite Web SQL: 3.36.0 (this is using whatever your browser uses, as pointed out by Jeroen Mostert in comments);
SQLite js: 3.15.1;
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU2) (KB4052574) - 14.0.3008.27 (X64) Nov 16 2017 10:00:49 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS);
```

And I determined these with the following methods:

```
MySQL, SQL Server: SELECT @@version;
Oracle: SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
PostGRE: SELECT version();
SQLite: SELECT sqlite_version()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: w3schools apparently relies on Web SQL functionality, so technically it should use whatever your browser uses for this, which can vary. Since I use Firefox (which doesn't support Web SQL) it uses MS Access server-side instead (as evidenced by the fact that executing `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` gives "This is a read-only, MS Access Database, and you are not allowed to do that.").

Comment: And sqlfiddle lets you choose the database which is even on your screenshot.

Comment: How about that.  Learn something new every day.  Which is why the version on w3schools is so current, because I'm using an updated version of Chrome, I suppose.

Comment: You are correct.  I don't generally use SQLfiddle, in favor of dbfiddle, and I checked for the ability to change sql engine and missed the dropdown.  I'll be editing this answer.

Comment: updated with the other sqlfiddle options. @GSerg